# problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_local_notifications' in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-local-notification

[image]

I downloaded my flutter project from git which I created 2 years ago. Now, when I try to execute `flutter run` command in command prompt than it shows the error regarding `flutter_local_notifications`.

app/build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mobigic.attendance"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }


    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: use old version of `flutter_local_notification` instead of update version.

Comment: Please read the guide on [formatting](/help/formatting) and stop abusing it. You're often seeting all text in your posts bold+italic, which just makes it difficult to read. Please do not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling cached packages fixd this issue:

```bash
flutter pub cache repair
```